# Detect click on sortable item that added with .append

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui-sortable

I'm creating 2 sortable lists, the items on that list added with append().
Everything working just fine, but i need to make the items move between lists on click.

I can't understand why the on click event on the li not working.

Here's are the codes:

**Append**

`$("#availble_contacts").append("<li class='contact_li'>" + contact + "</li>");`

**Move with clicks**

```
$('.contact_li').on('click', function () {
    console.log("click detected");
});
```

What am i missing?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the `contact_li` is added dynamically, you need to use [`event delegation`](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) to register the event handler

```
// New way (jQuery 1.7+) - .on(events, selector, handler)
$('#availble_contacts').on('click', '.contact_li', function() {
    console.log("click detected");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with find like

```
$('#availble_contacts').find('.contact_li').on('click', function () {
    console.log("click detected");
});
```

Or even you can use `delegate` method for the `click event` like

```
$('#availble_contacts').on('click', '.contact_li', function () {
    console.log("click detected");
});
```

Makesure that you have put the code in `dom ready`

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).on('click', '.contact_li', function () {
    console.log("click detected");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

See your lis in the .contact_li is dynamically created element so direct binding of js event wont be attached to it, so insteat of that you can delegate the event to the closest static parent like `"#availble_contacts"` in your case:

Change this:

```
$('.contact_li').on('click', function () {
```

to this:

```
$("#availble_contacts").on('click', '.contact_li', function () {
```

Answer (score 0):

you'd better bind the click event on the ul rather than the li, and detect the exact li by the "target" of the "event".

```
$("#availble_contacts").on("click",function(event){
    var e = event || window.event;
    var target = e.target || e.srcElement;
    console.log("you clicked "+target);
})
```